# Circle and container that overlaps

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this design of a circle that overlaps with a `Container`, I have tried to use a `Stack` and `alignment` but it is not working as expected.

[image]

The code I tried:

```dart
Stack(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 1000,
      color: Colors.black12,
    ),
    Container(
      //alignment: const Alignment(0, 0),
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 24, 39, 251),
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I am expecting to get the overlapping shapes as in the picture.